# ReactIS: the default value in the selection dropdown list is not be truely selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I have a select dropdown list, I want to set a default value to be user friendly. But what happen is if a user doesn’t change the selection to something else, I don’t get the actual value. I must have done something wrong, but what is it?

Here is my code:
In the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {};
   this.state = {
      …
      reward: this.props.milestone.reward || "",
      …
   };
this.onMilestoneRewardChanged = this.onMilestoneRewardChanged.bind(this);


render(){
<td className="input-group-sm col-sm-1">
   <select className="form-control"
         defaultValue={combinedRewards[0]}
         value={this.state.reward}
         onChange={(e) => this.onRewardChanged(milestoneIdx, e)}>
      {combinedRewards.map(this.renderRewardIDs)}
   </select>
</td>
}

renderRewardIDs(reward, idx) {
   return (
      <option key={idx} value={reward.id}>{reward.id}</option>
   );
}

onRewardChanged(Idx, event){
   this.setState({reward: event.target.value});
   …
}
```

so the first item in the list gets displayed as the default value, but if a user thinks that is already being selected and doesn’t change it to something else, the reward field ends up blank in the save data. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because of your initial state `reward: this.props.milestone.reward || ""`.

When you save it, if `this.props.milestone.reward` is undefined than the value will be `""` if no user interaction has taken place.

It's also unclear what the value of `combinedRewards[0]` is. If you set the defaultValue to `combinedRewards[0]` you should probably set the initial state to the same thing.

Maybe something like this?

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {};
   this.state = {
      …
      reward: this.props.milestone.reward || combinedRewards[0], // updated
      …
   };
this.onMilestoneRewardChanged = this.onMilestoneRewardChanged.bind(this);


render(){
<td className="input-group-sm col-sm-1">
   <select className="form-control"
         defaultValue={this.state.reward} // updated
         value={this.state.reward}
         onChange={(e) => this.onRewardChanged(milestoneIdx, e)}>
      {combinedRewards.map(this.renderRewardIDs)}
   </select>
</td>
}
```